# domains redirecting to specific pages

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, dns

I have a main domain name associated with a WordPress site, and then I have a couple other domain names connected to that site as well.

I want the other two domains names to point/redirect to specific pages on the site rather than the index page, which is the default.

So when `domain1.com` is typed into the browser, it goes to `maindomain.com/domain1page/` (this is how the permalinks are set up). Is this possible?

Comment: If you're using apache, mod_rewrite is your friend.  There's no call for using PHP (more overhead than strictly necessary), unless you have no other options.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `index.php` and upload it the root of `domain1.com`

```
<?php
    header("location:http://maindomain.com/domain1page/");
?>
```

OR if you do not have a Hosting package for `domain1.com` go to the Domain Manager and in  Nameservers you can enter a URL to redirect your domain to there.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you must add each domain manually. Just redirect them to your page.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - there are lots of different ways to do this.  Some registrars let you set up redirects at the domain level.  You could also have a website set up for each domain on your server, and then just redirect to the page you'd like from that.  You could also use the httpd.ini file to detect the domain and redirect to the appropriate page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small script that might serve the purpose.

You should place this at the top of header.php in your wordpress theme.

The script will not do anything if a domain is not matched so wordpress will load normal page. Haven't tested, but it should work.

```
<?php
$host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];    

//Setup Domains Directory Names Here
$domain1 = 'domainname1.com';
$domain1_dir = 'domain1directoryhere';
$domain2 = 'domainname2.com';
$domain2_dir = 'domain2directoryhere';
$domain3 = 'domainname3.com';
$domain3_dir = 'domain3directoryhere';

//Redirects to directory depending domain.
switch (true){
 case (preg_match("/$domain1/",$host)):
 header("location:/$domain1_dir");
 break;

 case (preg_match("/$domain2/",$host)):
 header("location:/$domain2_dir");
 break;

 case (preg_match("/$domain3/",$host)):
 header("location:/$domain3_dir");
 break; 
}
?>
```